# How to link the secondary y-axis to the correct variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart, yaxis

I am trying to overlay a bar and a line plot (see below) and have successfully done so and added a secondary y-axis. However, the variable of the secondary y-axis does not change when I add the axis, so it is barely visible at the very bottom of the plot. Is there a way to specify which axis should each variable fit to? I have tried modifying how bar and line plot are plotted (using stats instead of geoms, for example), but this doesn't make any difference.

Original plot 1:
[image]

Original plot 2:
[image]

Overlaid plot:
[image]

My code for the overlayed plot:

```
p<-ggplot(data=sparrowpop1,aes(x=as.factor(year)))
+stat_summary_bin(fun="mean", geom="col",mapping=aes(x=as.factor(year) , y=pop_size),color="darkblue", fill="white")
+geom_line(data=sparrowpop1, mapping=aes( y=freq, group=ID, colour=ID), stat="identity")
+scale_y_continuous(name="Population size",sec.axis=sec_axis(trans=~./30, name="Expected geneti frequencies"))
+xlab("Year")+ylab("Population size")
+theme_bw()+theme(text=element_text(size=23), legend.position="none")
```

A sample of my data:

```
> sparrowpop1[c(1:30),]
    X year pop_size   ID Sex    freq   id year1
1   1 2000      303 4153   1 1.00000 4153  2000
2   2 2000      303 4168   2 1.00000 4168  2000
3   3 2000      303 4177   2 1.00000 4177  2000
4   4 2000      303 4178   2 1.00000 4178  2000
5   5 2000      303 4189   2 1.00000 4189  2000
6   6 2000      303 4217   2 1.00000 4217  2000
7   7 2000      303 4255   2 1.00000 4255  2000
8   8 2000      303 4273   2 0.50000 4273  2000
9   9 2000      303 4274   1 0.50000 4274  2000
10 10 2000      303 4275   1 0.50000 4275  2000
11 11 2000      303 4303   1 0.50000 4303  2000
12 12 2000      303 4304   1 0.50000 4304  2000
13 13 2000      303 4333   2 1.00000 4333  2000
14 14 2000      303 4447   2 2.00000 4447  2000
15 15 2000      303 4455   1 2.00000 4455  2000
16 16 2000      303 4463   1 1.50000 4463  2000
17 17 2000      303 4464   1 1.50000 4464  2000
18 18 2000      303 4465   2 1.00000 4465  2000
19 19 2000      303 4468   2 1.00000 4468  2000
20 20 2000      303 4500   2 1.00000 4500  2000
21 21 2000      303 4501   2 1.00000 4501  2000
22 22 2000      303 4503   1 1.00000 4503  2000
23 23 2000      303 4504   2 1.00000 4504  2000
24 24 2001      338  104   1 0.50000  104  2001
25 25 2001      338  114   1 0.50000  114  2001
26 26 2001      338   20   1 1.00000   20  2001
27 27 2001      338  206   2 0.50000  206  2001
28 28 2001      338   23   1 1.00000   23  2001
29 29 2001      338   24   1 0.50000   24  2001
30 30 2001      338   32   2 0.50000   32  2001
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing people typically forget is that the secondary axis is just way to label the data and performs no transformations. Hence, you'd need to transform the data you want to have on the secondary axis yourself. Below, we'll use a `scalefactor` that we use to multiply the input data with and inversely, divide the transformation argument to the secondary axis by.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# Make dummy data with similar columns
sparrowpop1 <- expand.grid(year = 2001:2005, ID = 1:10)
sparrowpop1$pop_size <- rlnorm(nrow(sparrowpop1))
sparrowpop1$freq <- rlnorm(nrow(sparrowpop1)) / 30

scalefactor <- 30

ggplot(data=sparrowpop1,aes(x=as.factor(year))) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun="mean", geom="col",
                   mapping=aes(y=pop_size),
                   color="darkblue", fill="white") + 
  geom_line(mapping=aes(y=freq * scalefactor, # <- transform here
                        group=ID, colour=ID), 
            stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name="Population size",
    sec.axis=sec_axis(trans=~ . / scalefactor, # <- inverse transform here
                      name="Expected genetic frequencies")
  ) + 
  xlab("Year") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(text=element_text(size=23), legend.position="none")
```

[image]